# Pass ID prop to onChange for a materialUI Slider Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'd like to update my easy-peasy store when I change a value on a material-UI slider component. I need to pass the id of the slider component that I'm changing to my handleChange function so I can specify which property in my store I want to update. The problem I'm having is that onChange returns a different event target depending on which part of the slider you click on.

Click on rail returns:

```
<span class="MuiSlider-rail WithStyles(ForwardRef(Slider))-rail-37"></span>
```

Click on track returns:

```
<span class="MuiSlider-track WithStyles(ForwardRef(Slider))-track-36" style="left: 0%; width: 29%;"></span>
```

Clicking on the containing span returns:

```
  <span class="MuiSlider-root WithStyles(ForwardRef(Slider))-root-32 MuiSlider-colorPrimary" id="subdivValue0"><span class="MuiSlider-rail WithStyles(ForwardRef(Slider))-rail-37"></span><span class="MuiSlider-track WithStyles(ForwardRef(Slider))-track-36" style="left: 0%; width: 17%;"></span><input type="hidden" value="17"><span class="MuiSlider-thumb WithStyles(ForwardRef(Slider))-thumb-33 MuiSlider-thumbColorPrimary PrivateValueLabel-thumb-38" tabindex="0" role="slider" data-index="0" aria-label="test slider 1" aria-orientation="horizontal" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="17" style="left: 17%;"><span class="PrivateValueLabel-offset-40 MuiSlider-valueLabel WithStyles(ForwardRef(Slider))-valueLabel-35"><span class="PrivateValueLabel-circle-41"><span class="PrivateValueLabel-label-42">17</span></span></span></span></span>
```

Only clicking on the root span element returns a target with the id value when onChange is fired. Is there a way to get the material UI slider to return the id value no matter where on the slider I click?

> 

```javascript
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Slider from '@material-ui/core/Slider';
import { useStoreState, useStoreActions } from 'easy-peasy'

const PrettoSlider = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: '#52af77',
    height: 8,
  },
  thumb: {
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    border: '2px solid currentColor',
    marginTop: -8,
    marginLeft: -12,
    '&:focus, &:hover, &$active': {
      boxShadow: 'inherit',
    },
  },
  active: {},
  valueLabel: {
    left: 'calc(-50% + 4px)',
  },
  track: {
    height: '60%',
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
  rail: {
    height: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
})(Slider);

export function SubdivisionControls(props){

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    console.log(event.target)
    console.log(event.target.id)
    console.log(newValue)
    setStoreVal({id: props.id, targetSliderId: event.target.id})
   };

  const setStoreVal = useStoreActions(actions=> actions.panels.setParameter)

  return(
    <div>
     <PrettoSlider valueLabelDisplay="auto" aria-label="pretto slider 1" defaultValue={20} onChange = {handleChange} id = {'subdivValue0'} />
     <PrettoSlider valueLabelDisplay="auto" aria-label="pretto slider" defaultValue={20} onChange = {handleChange} id = {'subdivValue1'} />
     <PrettoSlider valueLabelDisplay="auto" aria-label="pretto slider" defaultValue={20} onChange = {handleChange} id = {'subdivValue2'} />
    </div>

  )
}

export default SubdivisionControls
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporary Solution:
Set pointerEvents to 'none' for all elements other than root for the slider:

```javascript
const PrettoSlider = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: '#52af77',
    height: 8,
    zIndex: 10,
  },
  thumb: {
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    border: '2px solid currentColor',
    marginTop: -8,
    pointerEvents: 'none',
    marginLeft: -12,
    '&:focus, &:hover, &$active': {
      boxShadow: 'inherit',
    },
  },
  active: {},
  valueLabel: {
    left: 'calc(-50% + 4px)',
  },
  track: {
    height: '60%',
    borderRadius: 20,
    pointerEvents: 'none'
  },
  rail: {
    height: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
    pointerEvents: 'none'
  },
})(Slider);
```